# Add cron.sh on crontab but cron is not working

Tags: cron, crontab

I added this line to crontab on our server

```
*/5 * * * * /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

but Aoe_Scheduler said last cron success was few month ago

What should I do to make cron is working?

Comment: Check http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10931/142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron.sh` by Magento has some issues. It spawns two processes, basically `php cron.php -mdefault` and `php cron.php -malways`, while STDERR is redirected to `/dev/null` (i.e. any error messages are swallowed).

So it is safer to set up the cron like this:

```
*/5 * * * * php /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php -mdefault >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * php /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.php -malways >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

However, you said you have `Aoe_Scheduler` installed. This extension comes with a drop in replacement for `cron.sh` that enables additional features in the cron management like process monitoring. The file is `scheduler_cron.sh` and you find instructions how to set it up in the "Scheduler" menu of the Magento admin panel (assuming you have version 1.x, or at least 0.4 of the extension - if not, update, it's worth it!)

Comment: it may be better to stick with cron.sh as it checks if cron is already running and doesn't run new cron in such case. In other case you may end up in multiple cron instance running at the same time.

Comment: another thing that is handled better by Aoe_Scheduler. But you are right, that's an argument against running cron.php directly, at least with default Magento

Comment: Actually code you showed with "default" and "always" run separately should work with cron.sh as well.

Comment: also, thanks for mentioning `scheduler_cron.sh`, I use AOE_Scheduler and I've somehow missed that this one should be run instead of cron.sh. I will check it.

Comment: I found I use 0.3.2 version of Aoe_Scheduler, and found 1.2.1 on github thanks to your advice for update. I'm trying to set cron base base on your advice, cron.php, cron.sh, scheduler_cron.sh Thank you! :)