# Why cron_schedule table is empty?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, cron, ce-1.9.2.4, schedule

I'm trying to run my custom module that setup two cronjobs. Here is my `config.xml` file.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <RLTS_Certification>
                <class>RLTS_Certification_Model</class>
            </RLTS_Certification>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <certi_status_update>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>RLTS_Certification/StatusHelper::updateCertiStatus</model>
                </run>
            </certi_status_update>

            <certi_renewal_reminder>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>RLTS_Certification/StatusHelper::certiRenewalReminder</model>
                </run>
            </certi_renewal_reminder>           
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

My cronjobs are not visible in `cron_schedule` table. One more thing is, that table is empty. What I need to do to setup these cronjobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `magento_root/cron.php` was not set in server `crontab`. We need to add this file in crontab so it worked for us as follow.

```
# crontab -l (this command will list all the Cron jobs in Crontab)
```

There should be an entry for magento_root/cron.php file. If not, we need to add this file because this file is responsible for initiating your Magento Cron jobs. So we need to edit the Crontab as follow.

```
# crontab -e
```

Add the following statement in the file and close after saving it.

> */5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -q path_to_magento_root/cron.php > /dev/null

For more information, visit this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=134)

Answer (score 2):

In your local system, you have to use your browser to run `http://yourdomain.com/cron.php` or `php-cli` to execute `cron.php` in the root of the application.

Comment: I tried **http://mydomain/cron.php** on my browser but It returns just an empty page.

Comment: Yes it returns empty page but now cron jobs are inserted in cron_schedule table.

Comment: but cron_schedule table is still empty

Comment: clear all cache and run it again. it works.

Comment: I remove var folder and again hit the cron.php file, but table is still empty

Comment: make sure that no error is generate while run cron.php and also check log for same. Also you can check by enable php display error log.

Comment: No error displayed,  ini_set('display_errors', 1); in index.php but still blank screen when hit cron.php. Also no error in var/log. Table still empty

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with the code for $isShellDisabled in cron.php
I commented out the two lines that were determining it (around line 50) and made the results be true.
$isShellDisabled = true;

The first time I ran it with that fix the table repopulated instantly and I do see changes each time the cron job runs.

Here's a thread on the same problem from ver 1.8:

[Magento cron.php Does Nothing After it Runs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/magento-cron-php-does-nothing-after-it-runs)

Comment: I explained why `$isShellDisabled = true` works and what the real solution to this problem is here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137130/is-adding-isshelldisabled-true-in-cron-php-recommended/137166#137166